# Perl overload @{} so that you can supply an object to foreach()

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

Is there a way I can make a class overload the array dereferencer in such a way that I can supply an instance of that class to `foreach` and have a custom function run at every iteration?

I tried:

- Overloading `@{}` and assigning it to a sub. However, in this case, the sub is only executed once and is supposed to return a reference to the array you want to iterate over. Almost but not quite what I wanted.
- Overloading `<>`. This executes the assigned function with every read attempt. Exactly how I want it, however it works with a `while` loop and not with `foreach`.

**overloading.pl**

```
use overloaded;

$class = overloaded->new();

$class->add("Hi");
$class->add("Hello");
$class->add("Yeet");

foreach $string (@$class) {
    print("NEXT ITEM: ".$string."\n");
}

while ($item = <$class>) {
    print("NEXT ITEM: ".$item."\n");
}
```

**overloaded.pm**

```
package overloaded;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use overload '@{}' => \&next, '<>' => \&fetchNext;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    $args{fields} = ();
    $args{pos} = 0;
    return bless { %args }, $class;
}

sub add {
    my ($self, $elem) = @_;
    push(@{$self->{fields}}, $elem);
}

sub fetchNext {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print("reading next line...\n");
    return $self->{fields}->[$self->{pos}++];
}

sub next {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print ("getting next array item\n");
    return \@{$self->{fields}};
}

1;
```

**output:**

```
$ perl overloading.pl
getting next array item
NEXT ITEM: Hi
NEXT ITEM: Hello
NEXT ITEM: Yeet


reading next line...
NEXT ITEM: Hi
reading next line...
NEXT ITEM: Hello
reading next line...
NEXT ITEM: Yeet
reading next line...
```

Comment: See [`Iterator::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Iterator::Simple) for an idea about how to implement this [(source)](https://metacpan.org/release/Iterator-Simple/source/lib/Iterator/Simple.pm)

Comment: Tip: Don't use lower-case module names for non-pragma modules.

Comment: Tip: `$class` is badly named. For starters, it doesn't contain a class but an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you're having here is not the difference between `@{...}` and `<...>` but the difference between `foreach` and `while`.

A `while` loop acts a bit like an iterator in as much as its execution looks like this:

```
while (you can run a piece of code and get back a value) {
  do something
}
```

So each time around the loop, it executes the piece of code in the `while` condition and expects to get a single value back. The code in the `while` condition is run in scalar context.

A `foreach` loop, on the other hand, only executes its code once and expects to get a list of values back. The code between parentheses at the start of the loop is executed in list context.

This is why you read a large file a line at a time using:

```
while (<$file_handle>) {
  ...
}
```

This only reads a single record from the file at a time. If you used a `foreach` loop instead like this:

```
foreach (<$file_handle>) {
  ...
}
```

then you would get all of the records back from the filehandle at once - which, obviously, takes far more memory.

Dereferencing an array reference works like that too. You get all of the values back at the same time. The overridden method (`next()`) will only be called once and will be expected to return a list of values.

Comment: thank you, I was entirely unaware that foreach makes a copy of an array first before iterating over its elements. So can I conclude that there's no way to actually treat an object as an array?

Comment: @bluppfisk: I didn't say anything about `foreach` copying an array. I said it generates a list of values. That's not the same thing at all :-)

Answer (score 2):

I show some techniques in [Object::Iterate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Iterate). Give your object some methods to supply the next value and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

[ *This adds to Dave Cross's answer rather than being an answer on its own* ]

Having a single iterator instance per collection cause all kinds of problem. That's why everyone uses `keys` instead of `each`, for example. As such, I strongly recommend that your class produces an iterator rather than being one itself, as the following does:

```
package My::Collection;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Iterator::Simple qw( iarray );

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);
    $self->{fields} = [];
    return $self;
}

sub add {
    my ($self, $elem) = @_;
    push @{ $self->{fields} }, $elem;
}

sub iter {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return iarray($self->{fields});
}

1;
```

Use it as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use My::Collection qw( );

my $collection = My::Collection->new();
$collection->add("Hi");
$collection->add("Hello");
$collection->add("Yeet");

my $iter = $collection->iter();
while ( my ($item) = $iter->next() ) {
   say $item;
}
```

You can also use either of the following more magical options:

```
while ( my ($item) = $iter->() )

while ( my ($item) = <$iter> )
```

Comment: thanks for the code sample. Could you add a line or two about the problems I might run into? I'm fairly new to Perl (and am also working on an offline system which does not allow to install packages :()

Comment: 1) Right now, you don't even reset the iterator when reaching the end, but that's easy to fix.

Comment: 2) The problems stem from leaving loops early (`for (1..2) { while (<$o>) { last if ...; ...; } }`) or from nesting iterations (`while (<$o>) { while (<$o>) { ... } }`). It's hard to create a convincing example, but this happens just often enough in practice to get surprising problems that are hard to debug.